# Calling api with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I want to call API with axios, and my problem is that when I paste the endpoint in my browser it return the JSON response, but when I call it with axios i got an error any idea why ?

```
axios
    .get("https://remotive.io/api/remote-jobs")
    .then((res) => console.log(res));

Error :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://remotive.io/api/remote-jobs' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: `remotive.io` doesn't allow CORS access - here's some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNtFSVU-YTI)

Comment: Got it, but can you explain to me how could this API be called inside, I mean is this something I can fix ? And if they won't allow it, why they made the API at first ?

Comment: generally it's not uncommon for OPTIONS responses to include CORES header 
 only for valid referrers, so while CORS could allow some origins,  it does not list http://localhost:3001.  You can't "fix" it, it's a configuration choine on `remotive.io` to stop you from calling their APIs on other websites.

Comment: *"is this something I can fix"* - if it's not yours, then it's not broken, it's functioning as intended. It possibly was never intended to be used direct from a browser - likely it was made to be used from your server to their server - *"why they made the API at first"* = not sure what that API is for, so I can't answer that